# Array 2d of struct in Python

Tags: python

How do i declare an array 2d of struct in Python ? In C++ i can do it :

```
 struct Network  {
   float   input ;
   float   output  ;
   float   delta  ;
   float  index [10];  
   } ;
Network  matrix [10] [10]  ;
```

In Python

```
class Network: 
    def __init__(self,input,output,delta,index): 

        self.input=float(input)
        self.output=float(output)
        self.delta=float(delta)
        for e in index : 
            self.index.append(float(e))

    def changeIndex(self,indice , newval): 
        self.index[indice]=float(newval)
```

So how to make a 2d struct in Python?

Comment: Isn't `self.index.append(float(e))` an error since you haven't defined `self.index` as a list prior?

Comment: Have you tried doing an array of arrays? `[[x*y for x in range(5)] for y in range(10)]`